# Bootstrap Button - No Hand Cursor

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing an MVC6 project in Visual Studio 2015. I have just added Bootstrap 3.3.6 using Bower. On a very simple html page I have referenced the CSS in the header and Bootstrap at the bottom of the body as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I defined a button as follows:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Hello</button>
```

When I debug the project (IIS, IE11) the button appears and is clearly styled by Bootstrap but there is no hand cursor.

If I use the browser to navigate to an example of a Bootstrap styled button, for example here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp, the hand cursor appears as I would expect. So it's not my browser at fault.

Can anyone suggest why I am not getting a hand cursor from a simple Bootstrap styled button please?

Comment: Check if there is a `pointer-events: none;` anywhere in your css. If yes, override it with `pointer-events: auto;` or if you're sure you want to edit the bootstrap source files, then just remove that line.

Comment: Did my answer helped you? if yes please accept it, if not, state what is not working.

Comment: There is nothing overriding the pointer-events, it's all very simple.

Answer (score 17):

Try add `role='button'` instead. I have had this problem even though the documentation on bootstrap says `type='button'` should do the work but mine didn't.

Comment: It worked for me. But while working in another project I remember I used `type='button'` and it worked. I don't understand the reason why it worked in that project but not in this one.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding an href such as href="#" to the button.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Hello</button>
```

When you start changing native element types and roles there are other side effects, including how those elements interact with accessibility for users. See this MDN link for details on that: [Button Role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role)

Answer (score 3):

You need to get rid of the button tags and just use anchor tags with bootstrap classes. For example:

instead of:

`<button class="btn btn-primary">Hello </button>`

write:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Hello </a>
```

This will make the HAND CURSOR appear when hovering over the btn bootstrap class

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the type="button".

In bootstrap source less file there are several css rules specified for the input[type="button"] rule. (**Checked for version 3.3.6**)

You might not have to use it, but it was intended to be used with type="button".

In both W3School and Bootstrap buttons demo page they are using type="button"

Your code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Hello</button>
```

W3:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
```

If it is still not working after adding type="button" (or submit or reset), try looking on your element with inspector and see what overrides the "pointer: cursor" css rule.

Comment: Adding `type="button"` didn't help. The code at w3schools above didn't include this type definition and that worked fine. Thanks though.

Comment: @waLLe "still not working.." - what exactly not working? what have you tried? where is your source code?

Comment: @waLLe recreate the issue on fiddle or post new question with your full code

Comment: @ZivWeissman it was my fault.. question using bootstrap 3, but I am using bs4.. just checked it, sorry for the misunderstanding.. +upvoted

Answer (score 0):

I was looking like you for a way to add this hand over, 
until I saw that hand appearing once the form was filled.
(was using

```
<button type="button"  >
```

by the way )

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new css:

   `.cursor-pointer { cursor: pointer; }`
2. Apply css on button:

   `class="cursor-pointer"`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. When `hover` over the `button` hand cursor is not shown instead mouse pointer is seen. Fixed it by using the following ways.

1st Fix:

```
<input type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Hello">
```

2nd Fix:

```
<a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Hello</a>
```